# Google My Business API (GMB) Fetch Locations Medias

Tags: google-api, google-my-business-api

GMB is changed from
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com to https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com

I am trying to fetch every locations medias. In previous version i can able to fetch medias like this url https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/locations/<location_number>/media

But it didn't work anymore even the new version doesn't work.
( https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/locations/<location_number>/media )

How can I able to fetch every locations media items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the media API endpoint was not migrated to a new media API yet, you still need to use the GET `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/{parent=accounts/*/locations/*}/media` endpoint.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.media/list

Comment: my mistake. I forgot to add accountNumber on url :S